# Openshift Istio Application

Tags: istio, openshift-origin

I have Installed Istio on Openshift v3.11 as system:admin. I have tried deploying applications with istio-enabled features as **admin**, but I am getting following error

> error when retrieving current configuration of:
>   Resource: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3, Resource=destinationrules", GroupVersionKind: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3, Kind=DestinationRule"
>   Name: "*****", Namespace: "****"
>
> from server for: "destination-rule.yaml": destinationrules.networking.istio.io "service" is forbidden: User "admin" cannot get destinationrules.networking.istio.io in the namespace "demo": no RBAC policy matched

Can't we deploy the applications with istio features as **admin** user? and How to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi, have you followed these instructions? https://istio.io/docs/setup/platform-setup/openshift/

Comment: @Joel Hi I have followed the same document. I just want to know if i installed istio in one user, I cant use it in another user?

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem, I don't know what is not working for you. I do same as you and it works

Comment: Well, the only different thing I do, is I'm not directly using system:admin, but I'm creating an account with admin rights. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Even I am not getting why its not working for other users except system:admin. Can you tell how to create/provide privilages/accessrights to other users (may be admin,developer,....) to access istio related pods.

Comment: Being logged as system:admin, I'm running: `oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin` then `oc login -u admin -p admin` . Then, being logged as admin user (not system:admin), I create a new project `oc new-project my-project` then `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z default`

Comment: It works for these commands finally. Thanks Joel.

As i have installed Openshift on aws ec2 instance, I want to see output of the  services deployed in web browser. How can i use ingressgateway externalIP in web browser? so that i can get output.

Comment: Well openshift brings the "Routes" resources which are a bit like ingress but (I believe) with more features and quite easy to use, see https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html and/or https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-ingress-vs-openshift-route/ (but you can still use kubernetes' ingresses it's explained on that blog post